# How to use order columns in other rows?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have 2 rows and i want order cols as examples:

```
<section class="row">
    <div class="col-12 order-1 order-sm-2">
     1
    </div>
</section>

<section class="row">
    <div class="col-12 order-2 order-sm-1">
     <img src="theme/images/contact.png" class="img-fluid mt-5"/>
    </div>
</section>
```

but each columns is in other rows and its not worked, i need every column in each row

please help

Comment: This is not how order is supposed to work at all. You can reorder columns in one row but not if the columns are in completely different rows.

Comment: Put the colums in the same row